# Hybrid join in DB2 z/os sql

Tags: sql, db2-400, ibm-db2

I have been rewriting decades old DB z/OS queries and there are three tables as below:

**customer**

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
|customer_id|state_code|city_code|
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

**customer_address**

```
+-----------+-------------+
|customer_id|facility_name|
+-----------+-------------+
```

**loan**

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
|loan_code  |state_code|city_code|
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

`customer = customer_address` is one-to-one and `customer = loan` is one-to-many.

We used to have two different queries to get list of customers by statewise and citywise, who have loans and are "active in business" (by having a record in customer_address!) as below:

```
SELECT CUST.STATE_CODE, CUST.CITY_CODE, CUST_ADRS.FAC_NAME 
FROM  CUSTOMER CUST, CUST_ADDRESS WHERE CUST_ADRS.ADR_ID <> 0 AND      
CUST_ADRS.CUST_ID = CUST.CUST_ID
```

The result of the above query is collected and each state and city is passed to below query from PreparedStatement. If there is a loan_id exists, then we collect the state, city and facility name.

```
SELECT CL.LOAN_ID FROM CUSTOMER_LOAN CL WHERE
CL.LOAN_CODE IN ('A1', 'BC') AND CL.STATE_CODE = ? AND CL.CITY_CODE = ?
```

I have rewritten these two queries into a single query. (There are indices in place for customer.cust_id, customer_loan.loan_id). I did not include loan_id in the modified query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUST.STATE_CODE, CUST.CITY_CODE, CUST_ADRS.FAC_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER CUST INNER JOIN CUST_ADDRESS CUST_ADRS ON 
CUST_ADRS.ADR_ID <> 0 AND CUST.CUST_ID = CUST_ADRS.CUST_ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_LOAN CL
ON 
CL.LOAN_CODE IN ('A1', 'BC') and
CL.STATE_CODE = CUST.STATE_CODE and
CL.CITY_CODE = CUST.CITY_CODE
```

Now I could see performance has significantly improved in the web application and query execution time takes some 700 ms. But I wonder if there is anything I can do to improve or modify this query. Any inputs or thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @CodeSlayer. Now I know how to format a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option which might be faster would be to use `EXISTS`:

```
select c.state_code, c.city_code, ca.fac_name
from customer c 
    join customer_address ca on c.customer_id = ca.customer_id 
where exists (
    select 1
    from loan l
    where l.state_code = c.state_code and
          l.city_code = c.city_code and
          l.loan_code in ('A1','BC')
    )
```

As always though, you need to test each query for yourself to see which performs the best.

Comment: Your query seems to be 15% more faster than mine as per Explain. I am going to use this one. Thank you